# Tiianium studio 3.2.0 Project intallation issue on Device

Tags: ios, titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

I am using titanium studio or sdk 3.2.0, my app is running on ios 6 and also 7 devices, but not running on ios 5 device. How can i fix it? And also i want to know how to set deployment target and mini sdk version in my project?

Answer (score 2):

> Note that support for iOS 5.x and earlier was removed in Release
>   3.2.0.

You can find this document and other useful information [in the appcelerator migration guide](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/iOS_7_Migration_Guide-section-37533766_iOS7MigrationGuide-Overview).

In order to support iOS5, you would have to compile with an older Version of the SDK, you can find a version history and the iOS versions supported [here](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Titanium_Compatibility_Matrix-section-29004837_TitaniumCompatibilityMatrix-iOSSDK%2FTargetiOSPlatform).