# Titanium: Setting minimum iOS version

Tags: ios, titanium, appcelerator

I googled this question and found that using

```
<ios>
  <min-ios-ver>#.#</min-ios-ver>
</ios>
```

takes care of just that. My problem is I am working on an app that I created several years ago now. My `tiapp.xml` never had an `<ios>` section. I still have an `<iphone>` section. I am currently using `Ti SDK 3.2.1` and my app works fine. I cannot get it to install on an iPad 1 with `iOS 5.1` on it. It is saying it doesn't meet the minimum software requirement.

So my question is how can I set this value for an older project? I have tried adding that tags above to my `tiapp.xml` but nothing. Itunes still says it doesn't meet the version requirement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Note that support for iOS 5.x and earlier was removed in Release
>   3.2.0.

You will have to use an older version of the SDK in order to compile for iOS 5.x

Please find the original answer and a few additional links about SDK compatability [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20993307/tiianium-studio-3-2-0-project-intallation-issue-on-device/).

Comment: Well that makes my dev iPad useless now. Time to decommission it to an entertainment piece. Thanks for the information.